# RACSignal for an NSArray of objects

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have an NSArray of ViewModel objects on my ViewController:

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *viewModels;

A ViewModel object looks something like this:

```
@interface ViewModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;

@end
```

I am trying to create a RACSignal for the enabledSignal on a RACCommand's init method:

```
- (id)initWithEnabled:(RACSignal *)enabledSignal signalBlock:(RACSignal * (^)(id input))signalBlock
```

This signal will tell the Command to be enabled if there are either 0 viewModel objects selected or if the number of viewModels selected is equal to the total count of the viewModels.

I can create a RACSequence which will give me the viewModel objects that are selected by this code:

```
RACSequence *selectedViewModels = [[self.viewModels.rac_sequence

                                        filter:^BOOL(ViewModel *viewModel) {
                                            return viewModel.isSelected == YES;
                                        }]

                                       map:^id(ViewModel *viewModel) {
                                           return viewModel;
                                       }];
```

**How would I go about creating the valid signal?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To observe all of the latest view models (and *only* the latest view models) for changes, we'll need to set up new KVO observations each time the array changes.

The most natural way to represent this is with a signal of signals. Each "inner" signal represents a set of observations on one version of `viewModels`, and then we'll use `-switchToLatest` to ensure that only the newest signal takes effect:

```
@weakify(self);

RACSignal *enabled = [[RACObserve(self, viewModels)
    // Map _each_ array of view models to a signal determining whether the command
    // should be enabled.
    map:^(NSArray *viewModels) {
        RACSequence *selectionSignals = [[viewModels.rac_sequence
            map:^(ViewModel *viewModel) {
                // RACObserve() implicitly retains `self`, so we need to avoid
                // a retain cycle.
                @strongify(self);

                // Observe each view model's `isSelected` property for changes.
                return RACObserve(viewModel, isSelected);
            }]
            // Ensure we always have one YES for the -and below.
            startWith:[RACSignal return:@YES]];

        // Sends YES whenever all of the view models are selected, NO otherwise.
        return [[RACSignal
            combineLatest:selectionSignals]
            and];
    }]
    // Then, ensure that we only subscribe to the _latest_ signal returned from
    // the block above (i.e., the observations from the latest `viewModels`).
    switchToLatest];
```

Comment: This fires when the viewmodels are first set but not when an individual viewmodel's isSelected property changes.

Comment: Kind of like my old C# / MVVM days, if I set the self.viewModels = self.viewModels after an object in the NSArray changes then this will fire.  Surely there is a better way?

Comment: @strickland Ah, sorry, that wasn't clear from the question. I've updated my answer.